# Boxplot of two vectors of different types

Tags: r, boxplot

So I *think* I have two vectors. The first one looks like this -

```
     70       71       72       73       74       75       76       77 
2.997500 2.680833 3.000833 5.443333 2.652500 7.115833 5.109167 5.730000 
      78       79       80       81       82       83       84       85 
6.866667 4.562500 4.725000 2.747500 3.861667 4.980833 3.940833 4.792500 
      86       87       88       89       90 
6.679167 3.100833 2.915833 3.904167 4.465833 
[1] "double"
```

Where the last double comes from when I do a print typeof of the variable that holds the vector(I guess it must be a vector of doubles).

I also use this function -

```
findLastRowVal = function(x){
    (tail(x[!is.na(x)],1))
}
```

with the apply function to find the last value of a bunch of rows in a data frame - these are the values -

```
     [1] "N" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "N" "Y" "N" "Y" "N" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "Y" "N" "Y"
[20] "Y" "Y"
```

I want a box plot in which I have two diagrams - one for the Ys and one for the Ns. If there is a Y in the corresponding index in the second vector, then said value in the first vector should be plotted in the box diagram for Y.

For example, 2.99750 corresponds with N and should be a part of the box diagram for N.

How do I achieve this?

So I attempted this now -

```
x <- data.frame(a=1:10, c=rep(c('Y','N'), 5))
jpeg("myplot.jpg")
boxplot(a ~ c, data=x)
dev.off()
```

but this gives me this error -

```
null device 
      1
```

I assume this is because there is no myplot.jpg (which is strange to me - why isn't R just creating one?) Where should I be creating this myplot.jpg?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a data frame and use the formula interface to boxplot:

```
x <- data.frame(a=1:10, c=rep(c('Y','N'), 5))
boxplot(a ~ c, data=x)
```

[image]

Comment: so I'm doing this in a r file and running from terminal - do I need to do anything else to see the plot?

Comment: Do you have a graphical workstation?  If so, it should open a plot window.  Otherwise you will need to explicitly open a graphical device (with e.g. `png`).

Comment: also, could you explain to me what's going on here? I don't see something like an 'if' statement

Comment: The (equivalent of the) `if` is buried in the `boxplot` code.  The formula `a ~ c` means to plot `a` conditioned on `c`.

Comment: what is c? what does the c = rep(c('Y','N'),5) part do?

Comment: In my example, `c` is a factor, which is what a data frame will create when given a column of text strings.  Factors are handy for conditioning (for graphs, and also for stats functions).  Here, it's a simulation of what you would get if you put your vector of 'Y' and 'N' characters into a data frame.

Comment: er..doesn't the rep mean that you're randomly generating the Ns and Ys?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45679/discussion-between-matthew-lundberg-and-praks5432)